# RealityKit – Interact with multiple Entity models

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I have two scenes in an `.rcproject` file, each scene is anchored with image anchor type, when an image is detected, the model appears. I want to add gestures to interact with the 3D model (`potteryAnchor1.pot1` and `potteryAnchor2.pot2`). However, only gestures for `potteryAnchor1.pot1` works. Below is my code:

```
potteryAnchor1 = try! Pottery.load_Pottery1()
potteryAnchor2 = try! Pottery.load_Pottery2()
arView.scene.anchors.append(potteryAnchor1!)
arView.scene.anchors.append(potteryAnchor2!)
        
potteryAnchor1?.pot1?.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
arView.installGestures([.all], for: (potteryAnchor1?.pot1 as? Entity & HasCollision)!)

potteryAnchor2?.pot2?.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
arView.installGestures([.all], for: (potteryAnchor2?.pot2 as? Entity & HasCollision)!)
```

I suspect that `potteryAnchor1` overlaps `potteryAnchor2` so I can't interact with `potteryAnchor2.pot2`. The two images below are `potteryAnchor1` and `potteryAnchor2`, respectively.

[image]
[image]

How can I achieve my goal?